# How do I use bash to generate a du mail report?

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script to email me a report of disk usage by directory.

Here is what I have (just testing right now, no emailing)

```
for dir in /Drive_E/*/;
do
    dir=${dir%*/};

    diskusage+=${dir};
    diskusage+="`du -sh ${dir}`";
    diskusage+="\n";

done;

printf $diskusage;
```

If I leave out the line with du bit in it, I do get a list of the directories.
How do I get the disk usage appended or prepended to the directory name?

Comment: Does quoting the variable in the `printf()` line help?

Comment: What do you get instead when you keep the `du` line?

Comment: Haven't tried quoting...I shall. As it stands, I get only the first subdirectory's info.

Comment: I assume the real code this came from is more involved than this and you cannot just output the data directly in the loop (and avoid the concatentation/etc. games entirely)?

Comment: @EtanReisner you are correct. I have to concatenate this same type output from several drives, into one email report.

Comment: `"\n"` is two characters, a backslash followed by an `n`, not a single-character newline -- that's `$'\n'`. If you want to evaluate escape sequences later, that's `printf '%b\n' "$diskusage"` -- see the APPLICATION USAGE section of the `echo` specification at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, describing `printf %b` as an alternative to `echo` variants that honor backslash-escape sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote `$diskusage` in the `printf` line. Without the quoting, it's splitting the variable into separate arguments at the whitespace in the `du` output, and only the first argument is the format string. The rest of the variable contents are the parameters to be subtituted for format operators, but there aren't any format operators.

So change it to:

```
printf "$diskusage"
```

Actually, this isn't the best way to write it, because you'll get incorrect output if there are any `%` characters in the filenames -- those will be treated as format operators. You should use:

```
printf "%s" "$diskusage"
```

Along with this, you'll need to change the line that adds a newline to `$diskusage` to put a literal newline in the string, not an escape sequence, because `printf` only interprets escape sequences in the format string. So that should be:

```
diskusage+=$'\n'
```

Comment: You mean `printf '%s' "$diskusage"`?

Comment: I think that the line with 'du' is including the directory. Using the info in this answer, I get the directory, followed by the disk usage (no space between), then space and the directory again. i.e. "/Drive_E/webserv1_html_bu8.0K /Drive_E/webserv1_html_bu"

Comment: I marked this as the correct answer, as it best fits into my desire to email the result.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to accumulate the output in a variable; just let it go to standard output.

```
for dir in /Drive_E/*/
do
    printf '%s %d\n' "$dir" "$(du -sh "$dir")"
done
```

You can capture it in a variable if you need to:

```
diskusage=$(
  for dir in /Drive_E/*/
  do
      printf '%s %d\n' "$dir" "$(du -sh "$dir")"
  done
)
```

Comment: If he captures it in a variable, he'll still have the same problem when he tries to mail the variable.